# How to access room DB in Work Manager to Sync Periodically?

Tags: android, mvvm, android-room, android-architecture-components, android-workmanager

I want to sync Room database periodically. I am using work manager to do it. I have created a periodic work request and I want to send a table with `setInputData(TABLE HERE..)`. I want to know if I am I doing it right. And if right, how can I send the table to work manager periodically? If wrong, please help me with a suitable solution.

Here is my code:

```java
//schedule recurring task only once
//Fragment
    if(!SessionManager.getBoolenFromPreferences(getActivity(),REFRESH_ATTENDANCE)){
        attendanceViewModel.setupPeriodicRefreshWork();
        SessionManager.putBoolenInPreferences(getActivity(), true, REFRESH_ATTENDANCE);
    }

//view model
public void setupPeriodicRefreshWork() {
    AttendanceScheduler.refreshWork();
}

//Scheduler
public static void refreshWork() {

    //define constraints
    Constraints myConstraints = new Constraints.Builder()
            .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
            .build();

  //How to Set Data Here ?
    Data source = new Data.Builder()
            .put(HERE)
            .build();

    PeriodicWorkRequest refreshWork =
            new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(AttendanceWorker.class, 1, TimeUnit.HOURS)
                    .setConstraints(myConstraints)
                    .setInputData(source)
                    .build();

    WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(refreshWork);
}
```

Here is my worker code:

```java
public class AttendanceWorker extends Worker {

    private Executor executor;
    private static final String TAG = "AttendanceWorker";

    public AttendanceWorker(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
        super(context, workerParams);
        executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    }


    @SuppressLint("CheckResult")
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        AttendanceDao attendanceDao = DatabaseInstance.getInstance(context).attendanceDao();
        Attendance attendance = attendanceDao.getAttendanceDetailsForSync();
        NetworkUtils.getAPIService().saveAttendanceDetails(attendance).compose(RxUtils.applySchedulers())
                .subscribe(
                        (AttendanceResponse attendanceResponse) -> executor.execute(() ->
                        {
                            if (attendanceResponse != null) {
                                if (attendanceResponse.getResult().equals("1")) {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "Attendance Synced!");
                                }
                            }
                        }),
                        Throwable::printStackTrace
                );
        return Result.success();
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you provide your `AttendanceWorker` code?

Comment: Hey @JeelVankhede I have not written code yet. But, once i get to know how can i access my database table. i will create a post request in the worker class.

Comment: Okay, Then one thing you can do is take some conditional parameter that determines which table you wanna interact with and then inside your Worker's `doWork()` method you'll have **applicationContext** to connect to your db & then get your conditional param as input and do condition intended work.

Comment: Context context = getApplicationContext();
        AttendanceDao attendanceDao = DatabaseInstance.getInstance(context).attendanceDao();
        Attendance attendance = attendanceDao.getAttendanceDetails().getValue();     getValue() returns null. I know it need to be quered async. So how can i access db table?

Comment: If You're executing code already inside `doWork()` method then no need to worry about **async tasks** because Worker already run on background thread.

Comment: attendanceDao.getAttendanceDetails().getValue(); returns null. How to solve this?

Comment: Solved it. Created one more method in DAO similar to previous one but Instead of LiveData<Object>, I have returned the normal Object and got the table with attendanceDao.getAttendanceDetailsForSync(); Added the worker code above.

Comment: Hi. I want to write some code to periodically synchronize my local database with my remote database. Could you write an answer explaining how your code turned out? My idea is a periodic synchronization (every 15 days) in which I fetch the data that is in a certain range of rows in a remote database table (one way synchronization).